# How do you get the 'Renaissance Man' achievement?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, defense-technica

Wondering how to obtain this achievement.

> Clear a stage by building all types and all levels of towers.

I understand what it says but I've tried what I have interpreted it is asking me to do.  If anyone has a videos or an explanation of how to do this it would be much appreciated.